# GET request on base64 Alfresco

Tags: javascript, get, base64, alfresco, alfresco-share

I'm trying to make a file request with this:

```
var connector = remote.connect("alfresco");
result = connector.get(PATH TO THE FILE);
    if (result.status == 200)
    {
        var data = result;
    }
```

And I get the all content of PDF in binary format. I want to convert to base64 but I want that the server make this before return the response. Anyone know how to make this?

I accept other type of resolutions without being with connector but `XMLHttpRequest or Alfresco. or YAHOO.util.Connect.asyncRequest('GET,url,callback)` don't works in server JavaScript, are undefined, so, I only know this resolution to get content.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi I don't understand you question clearly.

The code I use on Alfresco Repository JavaScript is the following:

```
var content = Packages.org.springframework.extensions.surf.util.Base64.decode(content);
```

And there is an `encodeBytes(byte[])` method as well.

Or you can just create your JavaScript extension and use any Java implementation you want.

Comment: Basically, I want to make like "XMLHttpRequest" on Alfresco, make a GET of the page http://something/pdf.pdf and when I get the PDF I don't want to get in binary file (like normal), I want in base64 but the server convert this and return. Not convert after make the GET. You understand ? if not, I try to explain better.

Comment: But I don't do XMLHttpRequest because javascript of Alfresco don't have this, and I get error "XMLHttpRequest" undefined, like if I make with Alfresco or YAHOO.

Comment: I don't understand you, There is a plugin to use XMLHttpRequest in Alfresco repository, we're using the plugin at the moment. 
So basically you want to get the content directly in Base64 right? so that is wat above code will do. Create a repo webscript wich encodes the document.content en your receiving end will directly get the encoded file.

Comment: One more question, in Which folder i have to create this javascript? And it is in repo and not in the share right? Im new on alfresco.

Comment: There are tons of tutorials how to create a repo webscript, look thes up.

Comment: But I don't understand one thing, I make all in one extension that have share and repo ... share is share.war and repo alfresco.war... I have to put this webscript on repo right ?

Comment: Can you give me a hint where to put one javascript in Alfresco Repository?I already try but i cannot access in share javascript to the other javascript.